# How can I merge identical rows but create a new column for unique values in R or Python?

Tags: python, r

I am looking to go from A to B on the attached image. I am new to coding and data manipulation and I can quite figure it out.

- Merge the duplicate first name and last name into one row but...
- Create a new column for the unique values.

Can this be done in `R` or `python`?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

What I tried:

```r
A %>%
  group_by(`Last Name`, `First Name`) %>%
  mutate(c2 = left_join('Course Name', 'Grade', by = c("First Name", "Last Name")))
```

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, we can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Last_Name, First_Name) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c("Course", "Grade")) %>% 
  select(Last_Name, First_Name, ends_with(as.character(1:4)))
```

**Output**

```
  Last_Name First_Name Course_1  Grade_1 Course_2 Grade_2 Course_3  Grade_3 Course_4 Grade_4
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1 Doe       Jane       English 1      90 Math 1        80 Science 1      95 NA            NA
2 Hope      Pray       Spanish 5      30 Latin 5       40 English 5      50 Math 5        60
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Last_Name = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Hope", "Hope", 
"Hope", "Hope"), First_Name = c("Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Pray", 
"Pray", "Pray", "Pray"), Course = c("English 1", "Math 1", "Science 1", 
"Spanish 5", "Latin 5", "English 5", "Math 5"), Grade = c(90, 
80, 95, 30, 40, 50, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```